# Open a seperate window when allowed value exceeded

Tags: php

I got syntax error when I tried to do the above mentioned task. What's wrong? Any guidance?
The idea is when columns are more than 9 in this case, because of space limitation, a button will be showed and by clicking the button, a seperate window will show more details. The separte window is not a problem here. Please see it here:

```
  <?php 
            $actionCount = count($this->actionpoints);
            $maxCols = 9;
            $actualCols = ($actionCount > $maxCols) ? $maxCols + 1 : $actionCount;

            if($this->permission_number<=9 && $this>view_permission['action_points'] ){
            $actualCols = ($actionCount > $maxCols) ? $maxCols + 1 : $actionCount;
            }else {$('#button').show();
              <input type="submit" value="show details"></input>;
            }             
            //followed by more codings...
   ?>
```

the syntax error is started from else line. Tks fr your advice in advance!

Comment: you are mixing html/javascript output with your server side php script which is generally a bad thing to do, and which leads to errors like this. consider using templates or at least designated view files

Comment: Thank you for our suggestion:-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
}else {
?>
  <input type="submit" value="show details" onclick="widow.open('new_url')"></input>;
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the think the correct code will be

```
<?php 
        $actionCount = count($this->actionpoints);
        $maxCols = 9;
        $actualCols = ($actionCount > $maxCols) ? $maxCols + 1 : $actionCount;

        if($this->permission_number<=9 && $this->view_permission['action_points'] ){
        $actualCols = ($actionCount > $maxCols) ? $maxCols + 1 : $actionCount;
        }else { ?>
        <script>    
            $('#button').show();
        </script>   
          <input type="submit" value="show details"></input>;
        <?php }             
        //followed by more codings...
?>
```